# How to Integrate CCAvenue Payment Gateway In AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, mobile, ccavenue

I am integrating cc avenue payment integration in my cordova mobile app. But I am getting error:

> "Something went wrong while processing your request. Don't worry... It
>   happens to the best of us."

I am unable to find the issue.

**Sample Code**`
 var pageContent =  ' +
            '' +
            '' +
            '' +
            '' +
            '' +

```
                   '</form> <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">document.getElementById("nonseamless").submit();</script>;
    var pageContentUrl = 'data:text/html;base64,' + btoa(pageContent);
```

`

Comment: A code example would help.

Comment: Your code sample is badly misformatted.